# Why win 10 display scaling is disabled

Tags: windows-10, scaling, dpi

I have win 10 Dell 7480 machine.
Integrated graphic card Intel HD Graphics 620.
The screen is pretty old CHIMEI-24EH HDMI, and is co connected with HDMI cable.

I am trying to adjust DPI scaling, but it disabled as can be seen the screen shoot.

[image: Display settings]

Question is whether it is because of the graphic card or is it the monitor limitation?
Actually I want to but a new monitor, and I just noticed this issue. I want to be sure it is not due to the graphic card.

Comment: I don't know from the above how old.  Try DISM and SFC.  dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup then dism.exe  /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth then SFC /SCANNOW and restart, test.  Update BIOS and Video drivers.   These settings work on my machines, the oldest of which is from late 2013 and is running 20H2 Insider.

Comment: Do you have a special display driver, e.g. NVIDIA or Intel, with its own special graphics settings, that may be disabling that setting? Also, there is the *dangerous* option of setting the DPI scaling in the Registry, https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5990-change-dpi-scaling-level-displays-windows-10-a.html . The danger is that the display could be made unreadable, and it would be difficult to recover from that issue.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik not sure what you mean. I have an Intel graphics with the its latest driver.

Comment: @John screen is at least 6 years old. Can it be a monitor limitation, or is it something with windows or hardware? Also, what "These settings" do you refer? Did you have the same problem?

Comment: It is probably the screen.  If you ran the tests above and nothing changed, then the screen is a possibility., You can run a Repair Install from the Media Creation Link to see if that fixes it.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: @John not sure whether you suggest **reinstalling** windows and also what exactly do you refer by _Repair Install_. I run SFC and DISM with no errors. It is possible to boot to win recovery, but the only "repair" there is _Startup Repair_ , but this issue is not a startup problem, so i am not sure what you suggest.

Comment: Since DISM and SFC ran properly, Repair Install is the next step. But that is not reinstalling Windows at all. It repairs the installation and the first option it presents is to keep all Data and Apps.

Comment: @John I "repaired"  and nothing is changed. I still wonder if it really can be that the screen itself is the cause? screen is just screen - display whatever it is fed with.  Isn't it? I actually tried it with my TV, but scaling was also disabled.

Comment: "I still wonder if it really can be that the screen"  I guess it could be - incompatibility between driver and screen.  The scaling setting certainly works here (all machines) and any client machine I have used.  Monitors are normally ViewSonic or Lenovo.